# How sink topic, kafka to kafka, using Flume?

Tags: apache-kafka, flume-ng

I am trying transfer log from topic to another topic. I need connect Kafka to Kafka using Flume. Take a look below:

```
#
# Flume Conf
#

a1.sources = s1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1


# Kafka Source

a1.sources.s1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
a1.sources.s1.kafka.bootstrap.servers = kafka:9092
a1.sources.s1.kafka.topics = apache


# Kafka Sink

a1.sinks.k1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.bootstrap.servers = kafka:9092


# Use a channel which buffers events in memory

a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 10000000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 1000000


# Bind the source and sink to the channel

a1.sources.s1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

The sink are not creating.

Comment: Why not use MirrorMaker (or other tool built into Kafka)?

Comment: This supports Kerberos? @cricket_007

Comment: If you want to continue here, what's the problem/error?? Where's the sink topic configuration?

Comment: Yes, MirrorMaker is just a wrapper around a regular producer and consumer. I don't know all the properties for the JAAS stuff and Krb5 JVM settings, but yes it supports it

Comment: I will try this. Thanks a lot @cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replicate data from one Kafka cluster to another, there are better ways than Flume, including:

- [MirrorMaker](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330), as @cricket_007 mentioned (open source, part of Apache Kafka)
- Confluent's [Replicator](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-replicator/index.html) (commercial tool, 30 day free trial)
- [uReplicator](https://github.com/uber/uReplicator) ([open sourced](https://eng.uber.com/ureplicator/) from Uber)
- [Mirus](https://github.com/salesforce/mirus) ([open sourced](https://engineering.salesforce.com/open-sourcing-mirus-3ec2c8a38537) from Salesforce)
- [Brucke](https://github.com/klarna/brucke) (open source)

If you want a *really* dirty hack, you can also [do something with `kafkacat` and `nc`](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/tree/master/export-import-with-kafkacat#sync-via-netcat).

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent.*